# Different versions of CKEditor and details about them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor in my ASP.NET MVC4 application.
But not getting the complete and detailed information about it.
I tried some links but still I am confused about it. There are some questions in my mind about CKEditor, They are...

1. Is CKEditor licensed or not?
2. Difference between 'CKEditor' and 'CkEditor Premium' 
    and 'CKEditor CDN' or any other if available.
3. Which one of above is to be used for any business or enterprise level application?
4. How to integrate it with my ASP.NET application.

Please help me with the above queries.
You can provide any link or example that can relate.

Thank you

Comment: Good place to get answer for this question - http://ckeditor.com/forums